# Firebase Cloud Functions Cron Async Func Multiple Calls

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-app-engine, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function. It is triggered by an App Engine Cron job. It triggers my Firebase Cloud Function every hour with a Google Cloud Pub/Sub. I fetch my Firebase Realtime Database once, and loop for every value. The problem is my main.async function called multiple times. I use an i variable for loop and my console logs more i count than my database length. I mean that if my database length is 4, but for loop runs 8 or 15 or 23 times. This values change randomly. I want to loop for my each database value,fetch some data on internet,and when it is done, go for next value. Here is the code:

```
use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var request = require('request-promise').defaults({ encoding: null });
var fs = require('fs');
// Get a reference to the Cloud Vision API component
const Vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const vision = new Vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
var os = require("os");
var databaseArray = [];
var uniqueFilename = require('unique-filename')

exports.hourly_job = functions.pubsub
  .topic('hourly-job')
  .onPublish((event) => {
    console.log("Hourly Job");

    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("myData")

   ref.once("value").then(function(allData) {

   allData.forEach(function(deviceToken) {

          deviceToken.forEach(function(firebaseIDs) {

        var deviceTokenVar = deviceToken.key;
        var firebaseIDVar = firebaseIDs.key;
        var firstvalue = firebaseIDs.child("firstvalue").val();
        var secondvalue = firebaseIDs.child("secondvalue").val();


        var items = [deviceTokenVar, firebaseIDVar, firstvalue, secondvalue];

        databaseArray.push(items);

});   

});
return databaseArray;
}).then(function (databasem) {

    main().catch(console.error);                
        });

return true;
});

const main = async () => {

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < databaseArray.length; i++) {

        console.log("Database Arrays " + i + ". elements: ");

         if (databaseArrayfirst != "") {

        var apiUrl = "http://api.blabla;

        try {
        const apiBody = await request.get(apiUrl); 


    ///////////////////////////vison start//////////////////////    

        const visionResponseBody = await vision.documentTextDetection(apiBody)

         var visionResponse = visionResponseBody[0].textAnnotations[0].description;

         ...some logic here about response...

/////////////////////////////////////////////////   
         var getdatabasevar = await admin.database().ref("myData/" + databaseArrayDeviceToken + "/" + databaseArrayFirebaseID);

         await getdatabasevar.update({
         "firstvalue": visionResponse
         });  


/////////////////////////////////////////////////  

} catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        }
///////////////////////////vison end//////////////////////  
    }

};
return true;
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: There is way too much code here. Please have a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to improve the chances that somebody will spot the problem.

Comment: This `databaseArray.push([...items])` seems weird. How about `databaseArray.push(items)`?

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen , but i did not work. I change the code but no luck. Sometimes it hangs on  if (databaseArrayfirst != "")  line, or vision api line. What should i do?

Comment: I am trying something about my code. But it doesn't work. @Mocas